# How to implement MVVM for function call?

Tags: function, mvvm, call

MVVM seem only works with data-binding.

How about if I want to call a function of a usercontrol that is created in the xaml?

For example, I made a graphical drawing usercontrol in which there is a function AlignTopEdge() that align all the selected graphics to the top edge.

I have a button called AlignTopEdgeButton and want to bind this button command to the AlignTopEdge() function of the graphical drawing usercontrol.

How could I do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in the code-behind the view, since it is view-specific logic. Your ViewModel should not know/care about aligning UI objects unless that is related to the business logic of your app somehow.

So in your case, I would just handle the Button's Click event in code-behind, find the UserControl, and call `myUserControl.AlignTopEdge()`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use case for an [attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx). e.g. you could have an attached property which has a `GraphicalControl` property, that you set to the instance of your user control in XAML.

In the setter for the `GraphicalControl` property, you can assign the `Click` event of the button instance to then call the method.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't understand clearly.
You mean to bind the whole GraphicalControl instance to the ViewModel?

Comment: How could I know the instance of the GraphicalControl in the code of attachedproperty?